# jQuery Selector: how can I specify one select menu when I have more than one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have 4 select menus, all with the same products. (User is supposed to use the select menus to add products to an invoice).

So each section is composed of a select menu, a quantity text field and a price text fields. But I have FOUR of those in the same page.

Whenever I select a product from the select menu, I want to change the quantity and price. But more specifically, I would just like to know, how to find out WHICH select menu was clicked.

if the select menus have a class of product (.product), when I select a product, ALL sections are affected. But I only want to affect that specific select menu section.

```
$(".product").change(function(event){
  alert('product picked'); // testing
});
```

I can't just append a number, like this: product1, product2, product3. Because then in the javascript file i would have to write 4 different functions

```
$(".product1").change(function(event){, 
$(".product2").change(function(event){, etc.
```

I know this is very basic, but I need to refresh my jQuery stuff.

This is some of the form HTML. I only included product select menu and quantity text field for simplification.

```
<div class="item">
<p>
  Product: 
  <select class="product" id="invoice_line_items_attributes_0_item_id" name="invoice[line_items_attributes][0][item_id]"><option value="1" data-defaultquantity="1">WP setup</option>
  <option value="2" data-defaultquantity="1">WordPress Theme Design</option>
  <option value="3" data-defaultquantity="1">WHE/yr</option>
  <option value="4" data-defaultquantity="1">WHE/mo</option></select>
</p>

Qty: <input class="quantity" id="invoice_line_items_attributes_0_quantity" name="invoice[line_items_attributes][0][quantity]" size="30" type="text" value="1"><br>
</div><hr>

<div class="item">
<p>
  Product: 
  <select class="product" id="invoice_line_items_attributes_1_item_id" name="invoice[line_items_attributes][1][item_id]"><option value="1" data-defaultquantity="1">WP setup</option>
  <option value="2" data-defaultquantity="1">WordPress Theme Design</option>
  <option value="3" data-defaultquantity="1">WHE/yr</option>
  <option value="4" data-defaultquantity="1">WHE/mo</option></select>
</p>
Qty: <input class="quantity" id="invoice_line_items_attributes_1_quantity" name="invoice[line_items_attributes][1][quantity]" size="30" type="text" value="1"><br>
</div><hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".product").change(function(event){
  $(this).closest(".section").find(".quantity").val("somevalue");
  $(this).closest(".section").find(".price").val("somevalue");
});
```

Comment: I ended up using this answer because there is more than one select menu. Instead of selecting the menu by id, it needs to be selected by closest in case the same product is selected in more than one select menu.

Answer (score 9):

In your event handler, `this` will be bound to the relevant `<select>` element.

```
$(".product").change(function(event){
  alert($(this).attr('name')); // name of <select> element changed
});
```

A handy trick is to use "data" attributes to relate something like that `<select>` to the other fields.  That is, you can do something like store the "id" of the related field in a data attribute so that the handler can find the field to mess with:

```
<select name='whatever' data-quantity-id="whatever" data-price-id="whatever">
  <option ... >
</select>
```

Then in the handler:

```
$('.product').change(function(event) {
  var $quantity = $('#' + $(this).data('quantityId'));
  var $price = $('#' + $(this).data('priceId'));

  // ...
});
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, which was similar to yours. Great answer.

Comment: And if you want to pass $(this) into a subfunction, you can use subfunction.call($(this), more_args...).  Might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks it did give me ideas for the data attribute. I did end up using Keith's answer because I have more than one select menu and the user might select the same product in more than one select menu. So I couldn't really use id's. But I can see how this is very useful in the case of one select menu, it's more clear and more concise.